# How to unhighlight the text before closing the Document

Tags: vba, macros, ms-word

I have a requirement that it should count the no. of words sentence-wise. If no. of words in sentence is more than 20, it should highlight it. & when user closes the Document. This highlighting should be disappeared. Below is the code that i have used. It's counting the no. of words & then highlighting also properly. But, How to un-highlight this when user closes that document?

```
Sub Count_of_words()
'
' Count Macro
'
'
    Dim s As Range
    For Each s In Selection.Sentences
        If s.Words.count > 20 Then
            With s.Font
                .Underline = wdUnderlineWavy
                .UnderlineColor = wdColorRed
            End With         
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Document_Close() event - just put code in it, and it will be executed before document is closed - You could use your original code, but instead of .Underline = wdUnderlineWavy and .UnderlineColor = wdColorRed use values that dont highlight text. Event procedure must be in ThisDocument file, not in module file (You find it in Project Explorer). So, basicly, open ThisDocument and write procedure:

```
Sub Document_Close()
'
' Count Macro
'
'

Dim s As Range
For Each s In Selection.Sentences
    If s.Words.count > 20 Then
    With s.Font
                .Underline = 'put code to no underline
                .UnderlineColor = 'put code to no color
            End With


End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I used Document_Close() Event & stored that event in a template. Then i made that Template Global. It's not working globally.

Comment: it's not firing Document_Close() for me when i am closing the Word Document.

Comment: Try  Private Sub Document_Close() instead of Sub Document_Close(), or choose this procedure from combo boxes on top side of visualBasic editor, maybe it helps.